# Change the filename for file uploads in channel forms - non image files

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, channel-form

I have an internal site on ExpressionEngine that allows employees to upload files using channel forms (formerly safecracker). I would like to change the name of the file to include the username of who uploaded it.

I have seen solutions here on stackexchange for doing this with image files with an add-on CE Images. I'm wondering if there is a solution for non-image files, preferably without an add-on.